# Included mysqli_connect inside a function fails, why?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've seen a few people with this same issue, yet none of the answers solved my problem. This is what I have in three files:

index.php:

```
 $dbconnect = connectDB("mydb","connect");
 mysqli_query($dbconnect,"INSERT INTO `mytable` (field1,field2) values ('value 1','value 2')");
 connectDB("","kill",$dbconnect);
```

functions.php

```
 function connectDB($db_name,$connectorkill,$link) { include('connectDB.inc.php'); }
```

connectDB.inc.php

```
 $host="localhost";
 $user="myusername";
 $pass="mypassword";
 if($connectorkill == "connect") {  
 if($dblink = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name)) {
 echo "dblink created.";
  return $dblink;
 } else { echo "Error connecting to database."; }  
 } elseif($connectorkill == "kill") { mysqli_close($link); }
```

and what I get is:

```
 Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/username/public_html/members/index.php on line 2
```

which looks like the connectDB function is not doing its job, specifically the return of the $dblink variable in connectDB.inc.php. I went ahead and moved the code from connectDB.inc.php to inside the functions.php and it solved the problem, but I don't want it set up that way. Is there a way to solve this error?

Comment: Your `connectDB()` doesn't return anything. the return in `connectDB.inc.php` becomes the return value of `include` (which you discard by not passing it along). Also: Why are you having your connectDB code inside that extra file instead of in the function directly in the first place?

Comment: Please post the full code of ConnectDB.inc.php

Comment: What you see is the full code.

Comment: @ccKep I have my reasons! But thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

**Solution 1**: Refractor your code, something along the lines of:

config.php:

```
$config = array(
    "databases" => array(
        "my_database" => array(
            "host"  =>  "localhost",
            "user"  =>  "myusername",
            "pass"  =>  "mypassword"
        )
    )
);
```

functions.php:

```
require("config.php");

function connectDB($dbname)
{
    global $config;

    if (!isset($config["databases"][$dbname]))
        return; // error, database info not in $config

    $dbc = $config["databases"][$dbname];

    $dbcon = mysqli_connect($dbc["host"], $dbc["user"], $dbc["pass"], $dbname);
    if (!$dbcon)
        return; // unable to connect error goes here

    return $dbcon;
}
```

Note that this is just the bare minimum of a connectDB function. There really should be more error checking in there (for example, on each of the `$dbc` keys. It also needs proper error reporting and such, this is just a general hint in the right direction.

**Solution 2**: Add `return` in front of your include...

```
function connectDB($db_name,$connectorkill,$link) { return include('connectDB.inc.php'); }
```

Regardless of the solution: You **really** need some error checking code in your index.php because no matter what you do: Your connectDB function isn't always going to return a valid database connection.

Comment: Your solution 2 works, I was not returning the include (didn't know I needed to do that, thanks!).

Comment: Also, regarding error checking, I left it out because I knew what the problem was, just didn't know how to fix it.